# Undelete Ubuntu One files, deleted with reconnected PC

Tags: ubuntu-one

I just reinstalled Ubuntu 10.10 with the same PC name as it was before.

So after reconnecting to Ubuntu One my files lost (I think because in my new system folder which has Ubuntu One synchronized files become empty after reinstall). How can i undelete these files?

Answer (score 2):

So, the reason why files became inaccessible was the removal of the UDF upon the connection of a new machine. The reason for that behavior has to be determined. The UDF was recovered on the server side and now I am awaiting the confirmation from Khoss.

**Update**: Khoss confirmed that the files are now available.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch, that is certainly a big problem. At the moment there is not way to do so, but I know as a fact that you will get some help in #ubuntuone in freenode since they will nee your details etc...

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy the ~/.local/share/ubuntuone directory to your new Ubuntu 10.10 install from the old one? If you did that but didn't have all your files in your synced folders, then Ubuntu One would see the files as being deleted and would remove them from storage.

The best way to get help with deleted files is to contact Ubuntu One support directly, as we'll need to look up your account information: https://one.ubuntu.com/support/contact